# Am I understanding processors and cores right?

Tags: cpu

I purchased a Supermicro board with a D-1541.  Intel ARK specifies it has 16 threads (and if you click the question mark, it says that is per core).  My Debian install shows 8 cores, 16 threads total. So is it really 2 threads per core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The ARK page for the D-1541](https://ark.intel.com/products/91199/Intel-Xeon-Processor-D-1541-12M-Cache-2_10-GHz) says that it has 8 cores and 16 threads. Those numbers are for the overall package: the D-1541 has 8 cores, each of which can handle two threads, for a total of 16 threads. This matches what your operating system is telling you.

Where did you see that the Intel sites says it has 16 threads per core?

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/91199/Intel-Xeon-Processor-D-1541-12M-Cache-2_10-GHz - Go here and click on "# of Threads".  The description reads: # of Threads
A Thread, or thread of execution, is a software term for the basic ordered sequence of instructions that can be passed through or processed by a single CPU core.

Comment: OK, but note the start of the sentence: “**A Thread**”. This is describing a thread, not describing the value.

Comment: BTW I have this board too, and it most definitely is an eight-core system with two threads per core (unless you disable hyper-threading).

Comment: I used to have an i3-4330v4 as my server.. did I downgrade by going to 2.1ghz 8 cores (16 threads) from the faster processor with 4 threads? And glad to know you have the same board

Comment: That depends on your workload... The D-1541 is really good at processing tasks which can be split up across many cores, and it still has a decent top speed (2.7GHz), but speed-sensitive single-core workloads obviously don’t run as well. It’s a compromise: lots of threads, lots of RAM with ECC, lots of networking, with a small power envelope, but not a speed demon on single threads.

Comment: I really need no speed on most threads, but 128MB ECC would be nice (I only have 16gb now, this is a home project and I'm slowly pouring tons into it). I just want to make sure my pfsense virtualbox idea will work well with the combo.  Give it some ram and a cpu and I hope the dual 10Gbe will be fine for a virtualized firewall